# Trying to determine quartiles for three columns in my dataset

Tags: python

I have three columns that i'm trying to determine its quartiles.

```
quantiles = rfm['a', 'b', 'c'].quantile(q=[0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80])
```

But i get the error: KeyError: ('a', 'b', 'c')

I would like my output to return :

```
        a   b       c
0.25    5.0 30.0    1145.0
0.50    6.0 75.0    2257.0
0.75    8.0 183.0   3784.0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost right, but you have to pass in the list of columns inside a list object, e.g., with another set of brackets

```
quantiles = rfm[['a', 'b', 'c']].quantile(q=[0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80])
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a downvote or two. I'm glad I could help you.